# Nothing provides buffer needed by mondo (dnf)

Tags: centos, dnf

Using `dnf` in CentOS 8, I tried to install **Mondo Rescue**, but failed with the following messages. I cannot understand what happened. Could anyone please show me how to fix the problem?

```
$ curl -OR ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org/centos/8/x86_64/mondorescue.repo
$ sudo mv -i mondorescue.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/
$ cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
$ dnf list mondo
centos 8 x86_64 - mondorescue Vanilla Packages                      1.3 kB/s |  12 kB     00:09
Available Packages
mondo.src                                  3.3.0-1.centos8                               mondorescue
mondo.x86_64                               3.3.0-1.centos8                               mondorescue
$ sudo dnf -y install mondo
CentOS-8 - AppStream                                                9.3 kB/s | 4.3 kB     00:00
CentOS-8 - Base                                                     8.4 kB/s | 3.9 kB     00:00
CentOS-8 - Extras                                                   4.8 kB/s | 1.5 kB     00:00
CentOS-8 - PowerTools                                                16 kB/s | 4.3 kB     00:00
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64               12 kB/s | 9.8 kB     00:00
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                       18 kB/s | 9.3 kB     00:00
centos 8 x86_64 - mondorescue Vanilla Packages                      1.3 kB/s |  12 kB     00:08
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides buffer needed by mondo-3.3.0-1.centos8.x86_64
  - nothing provides afio needed by mondo-3.3.0-1.centos8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s a package requirement that’s hard-codes into the package [spec file](ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org/fedora/31/x86_64/mondo.spec). I don’t see any repositories that provide it. The Debian package doesn’t list a homepage either, just a reference to the defunct [sunsite.org.uk](http://sunsite.org.uk/public/public/packages/buffer/) site where it was published, back in 1997.

I imagine that no other distro supports it anymore other than the Debian-based ones.

I suggest you file a bug, since it’s pretty clear no one ever tests that software on Fedora yet continues to package for it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick comments and suggestion.